# Hide extention behind a flag

Tags: siri, sirikit

I have added an app extention to handle sending message using siri, and i want to hide the entire thing using a feature Flag.
My desired behaivor is that when a flag is on, to have the interaction otherwise just having siri "This app has no support for siri"

I tried to add a flag in build settings